# GLSL flip a multisampling texture 2d into multisampling texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a multisample fbo and i want to flip it vertically into another multisample fbo. I am trying something as simple as:

```
#version 400 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2DMS textureMS;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texelFetch(textureMS, ivec2(TexCoords), gl_SampleID);
}
```

As official doc says that as soon as you're using gl_SampleID the fragment will be executed once per sample i though it should work.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: What is `TexCoords`, pixel coordinates or in range [0, 1]? [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml) requires pixel coordinates and performs a lookup of a single texel. Possibly you are searching for [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) - `texelFetch(textureMS, gl_FragCoord.xy, 0)`. But the issue is unclear.

Comment: FragColor = texelFetch(textureMS, vec2(0, 1)-TexCoords, gl_SampleID);

Comment: Nicol you were right, the question was not clear. It was just that it wasn't working. I didn't realized about the coordinates stuff and i was using [0, 1] coordinates. Thank you so much